# Django REST Framework: does source kwarg work in SerializerMethodField?

Tags: django-rest-framework

**Do `SerializerMethodFields` accept the `source=` kwarg?**

I have been running to a bug where I've been consistently passing in a value to the `source=`in `SerializerMethodFields` but it is always ignored. That is, the argument passed as `obj` to my `SerializerMethodField` is always the instance I am trying to serialize itself (e.g. `source='*'`).

The DRF Documentation says there are certain [core arguments](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments) that all field types should accept include the `source=`argument.

With that said, the DRF Documentation says this about `SerializerMethodField`:

> SerializerMethodField
>   This is a read-only field. It gets its value by calling a method on the serializer class it is attached to. It can be used to add any sort of data to the serialized representation of your object.
>
> **Signature**: `SerializerMethodField(method_name=None)`
>
> `method_name` - The name of the method on the serializer to be called. If not included this defaults to `get_<field_name>`.
>
> The serializer method referred to by the `method_name` argument should accept a single argument (in addition to `self`), which is the object being serialized. It should return whatever you want to be included in the serialized representation of the object.

Which did not leave me with a convincing answer as to what the expected behavior should be like for `source=` since it does not say that *no other core kwargs are applicable*.

Any insight with respect to what the expected behavior is for the `source=` in `SerializerMethodField` would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of snooping into the source code for `SerializerMethodField` and saw this

```
class SerializerMethodField(Field):

    # ...ignoring useful docstrings for brevity...

    def __init__(self, method_name=None, **kwargs):
        self.method_name = method_name
        kwargs['source'] = '*'   # <--  and here's our answer
        kwargs['read_only'] = True
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

I would have been nice if the DRF documentation for `SerializerMethodField` was more explicit in saying that none of the other [core arguments](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments) applied here but such is life.

**Answer**: No, the `source=` is **not** a respected argument.